# Aws s3 Multi Region Access point get image url for best latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've tried for an hour getting the url of images uploaded to my buckets, which i can get i've created replication rules for 2 different regions.

My question is how can i get the url of the image uploaded in both region buckets (Multi-Region-Access-Point), but the one which gives the best latency. how should the url look like ?

Comment: Are you looking for AWS CloudFront?

Comment: @user6346643 no, i've created a multiregion with 2 buckets. so how it works will it get the object from the best latency bucket even if i specified with us-east-1 credentials ? or how should i use the credentials in order to use Multi region access point .

Comment: <MRAP_alias>.accesspoint.s3-global.amazonaws.com
This doesnt work for me !

Comment: Did you append the object key to the URL, eg `xyz.accesspoint.s3-global.amazonawx.com/foo.jpg`, and make a Bucket Policy or set the ACL to Public? Here's a video on YouTube showing it working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0GTyLtWyUA

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes i did make my two buckets public i can access the object in separate buckets, but i want aws to choose which bucket is better for me and give it from the best bucket.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the **full** URL you are using, and what error message you are receiving?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein im not receiving any error my two buckets work, but i have to change the url in order to get from each url, object names are the same but the url changes from region to region. So i want to know if its possible to have only one url and aws chooses the best latency url to provide for the user.

Comment: Yes, the video I linked shows that it is possible. If you want some assistance is diagnosing your situation, please see the above requests for more information.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Multi-Region Access Point, it will automatically make use of AWS Global Accelerator to route to the best bucket:

> AWS Global Accelerator ingresses traffic from the edge location that is closest to your end clients through anycast static IP addresses. Then traffic traverses the congestion-free and redundant AWS global network, which optimizes the path to your application that is running in an AWS Region. AWS Global Accelerator chooses the optimal AWS Region based on the geography of end clients, which reduces first-byte latency and improves performance by as much as 60%.

More details here: [Always-on access for your data in Amazon S3, using cross-Region replication and Multi-Region Access Points (MRAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws/articles/76250275/always-on-access-for-your-data-in-amazon-s3-using-cross-region-replication-and)